# Ошибка при вычислении первообразной

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, sympy

Мне требуется найти первообразную от следующей функции

```
k * (1 + a * x**(1/2) + b * x**(0.7) + c * x**(0.9))**(d)
```

`X` - переменная, остальные какие-то константы.
Следующий код ничего не даёт, не могу найти ошибку или какое-то другое решение.

```
x,y,a,b,c,d,k = symbols("x,y,a,b,c,d,k")
sympy.integrate(k * (1 + a * x**(1/2) + b * x**(0.7) + c * x**(0.9))**(d) , x)
```

Comment: Производная это `derivative`

Comment: WolframAlpha с вашей первообразной тоже [не справляется](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+k+*+%281+%2B+a+*+x**%281%2F2%29+%2B+b+*+x**%280.7%29+%2B+c+*+x**%280.9%29%29**%28d%29+dx). Вы уверены, что она вообще берется в аналитических функциях?

Comment: так вам нужна производная или первообразная в итоге ?

Comment: опечатался в начале, но уже решил проблему другим способом без вычисления

Comment: Проявите уважение к отвечающим: исправьте вопрос или удалите его.